# Jenkins Pipeline With Parallel Command

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I have this basic jenkis Pipeline

Note: I omitted `subJobParams` to keep code smaller

```
pipeline {
    agent any 
    stages {

        stage('stage1') {
            steps {
                script {
                    parallel (
                                "mongoParallel" : { build job: 'mongo', parameters: subJobParams },
                                "elasticsearchParallel" : { build job: 'elasticsearch', parameters: subJobParams }
                                "redisParallel" : { build job: 'redis', parameters: subJobParams }

                    )
               }
          }
      }
  }
```

The external jobs are not running in parallel? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: whats showing in the console, are the jobs starting. Also verify the path of the external jobs to start

Comment: I believe `parallel` is for `stages` and not jobs. You would likely need a stage for each job for this to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the [Build Flow Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin) documentation's parallel for details.
To add, below is the snippet that I'm using in my pipelines.

```
stage('Name') {
  steps {
    script{
      container('tools') {
          parallel job1: {
              build job: 'path/to/the/job', parameters: [string(name: 'command', value: 'command-out')]
          }, job2: {
              build job: 'path/to/the/job', parameters: [string(name: 'command', value: 'command-out')]
          }, job3: {
              build job: 'path/to/the/job', parameters: [string(name: 'command', value: 'command-out')]
          }, job4: {
              build job: 'path/to/the/job', parameters: [string(name: 'command', value: 'command-out')]
          },
          failFast: true
      }
    }
  }
}
```