# How do i do configuratioin for different jobs has to run on different VMs or slave parallely

Tags: jenkins, automation, devops, hudson

suppose that both the project are freestyle or one is freestyle and other is pipeline project
how do then we will configure such that we  will able to run both the jobs or project simultanously or parallely

Comment: What is your question here bro? Trying to run multiple jobs parallely on different VMs or Slaves OR to run multiple jobs parallely in Jenkins?

Comment: suppose that i have two slaves node and a master jenkins. i want to run jobs such that  one jobs run at one Slave VMs and other  different job run on other availabe Slave VM

Comment: It is possible. Check [Jenkins Distributed Builds](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds). Restrict your job to run on a specific node in job configuration and you can call 2 different jobs of it's own configuration to run parallely from one parent job as mentioned in this thread. [Jenkins Pipeline With Parallel Command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60647936/10363259)

Comment: Thanks for your the help ,its  working now