# Jenkins schedule builds one after another

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I need to run 5 **Jenkins** `build` starting from midnight. For each `build` execution time may be different.

Currently, I'm scheduling the builds periodically in the pipeline.

> Schedule: 0 0,2,4,6,8 * 10 *

each build takes up to 1:15 hrs some may take less than an hour if some failures occur. I need to run `builds` after the previous `build` is completed. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Your builds are configured as pipelines or you have created 5 jenkins projects (e.g. Maven project)?

Comment: Did you check [Build Pipeline Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-pipeline-plugin/)?

Comment: Builds are configured as pipelines

Comment: have a single job scheduled to run by midnight. Call your 5 jobs in the order you want. This way, you'll acheive what you need.

Comment: i need to run same job 5 times.

Answer (score 3):

Below works everytime and is easy too.

```
pipeline {
   agent any
   triggers {
     cron 'H 0 * * *'
   }
   stages {
        stage('Test') {
          steps {
            script{
              container('tools') {
                 build job: 'path/to/job1', parameters: [string(name: 'tag', value: '123')]
                 build job: 'path/to/job2', parameters: [string(name: 'tag', value: '123')]
                 build job: 'path/to/job3', parameters: [string(name: 'tag', value: '123')]
                 build job: 'path/to/job4', parameters: [string(name: 'tag', value: '123')]
                 build job: 'path/to/job5', parameters: [string(name: 'tag', value: '123')]
             failFast: true
              }
            }
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Cron is set to trigger the job everyday by midnight. Once the above job runs, it starts running all the other jobs sequentially. Use the above snippet for running 5 different jobs sequentially.

If you want to run the same job 5 times, then replace those 5 lines of build jobs above to below.

```
     for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        build job: 'path/to/the/job', parameters: [string(name: 'tag', value: '123')]
     }
```

Comment: If you want to run 5 different jobs parallely, you can check this thread --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/60647936/10363259